# Store object to postgres varchar column as Json using Micronaut Data

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, micronaut, micronaut-data

Is it possible to automatically serialize/deserialize java object to single varchar/text column in postgres without manually using objectMapper etc? I only use Micronaut Data without Hibernate.

For example let's imagine this case:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    id int not null primary key,
    name varchar not null,
    address varchar not null
);
```

```java
@MappedEntity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String streetNumber;

    // getters and setters
```

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

I tried to use annotations like `@Serdeable` or `@JsonProperty`, but I must be missing something, because I get an `RuntimeExceptionHandler` error with a message:

```
Unexpected error in XYZ project: Error executing PERSIST: Unable to set PreparedStatement value: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of x.y.z.Address. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

The only solution that I could come up with was to change address attribute in person class to String and then manually map the response using Jackson's `objectMapper`. But then I would need to create another class and map Person and Address into it.

Is it possible to serialize/deserialize it just by using some annotations etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems I found a solution. Both classes need to be annotated with `@Serdeable` annotation and in Person class use `@TypeDef(type = DataType.JSON)`  annotation on `address` attribute.